# Update join function is not working properly in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys I have update `join` function where it will update the column.

If I try to delete the company it will change the status of the company and as well as if is there any users under that company it will change user status to `0` till now its fine.

But what my problem is i**f I don't have any users under that company that delete function is not working**. Can any one help me how to resolve this issue?

I would like to update the company status if there is no users also. If there is users it has to update from both tables.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
require('../config.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION['can_access']) || $_SESSION['can_access'] !== true ) 
    header('Location: login.php'); 

global $DB,$USER; 
$userid=$USER->id; 
$deletedon = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
$id = $_GET['id'];; 
$DB->execute("UPDATE {ppc_company}  mpc 
              JOIN  mdl_user mu ON mpc.cid=mu.skype 
              SET mpc.deletedby = '$userid', 
                  mpc.deletedon='$deletedon', 
                  mpc.status= '0',
                  mu.trackforums='0'  
              WHERE mpc.cid = '$id' and mu.skype='$id'"); 

header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
?>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it your intention to use an INNER or an OUTER join? afaik if you only specify "join" it defaults to an INNER JOIN

Comment: It is your WHERE condition which does not allow to update on your `mpc` table. `mu.skype='$id'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a `JOIN` (`JOIN` is defaulting to `INNER JOIN`).
This should update the main table even if the join returns null.

Comment: Also move ` and mu.skype='$id'"` to the left join condition. As long as it's in the where clause it effectively behaves as an inner join, because the user must still be there.

Comment: Are the curly braces proper syntax around the table name?